# Formatting values dynamically based on length

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have input data as below

[image]

I want to add leading 0s to the PRODUCT_NUMBER to make it total 10 digit , desired output should be like below

[image]

Is there a way to do this in snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use TO_CHAR function to format the numbers:

```
select TO_CHAR( num, '0000000000' ) AS res from values
(145678),
(3456),
(12) tmp(num);

+------------+
|    RES     |
+------------+
| 0000145678 |
| 0000003456 |
| 0000000012 |
+------------+
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is `lpad` which dynamically pads specified character until the string reaches the length N. If the length of string was > N to begin with, it will return first N characters and truncate the rest.

```
select lpad(col, 10, '0')
```

[**Documentation**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html)